# org.json.JSONException: Expected a ',' or ']'

Tags: arrays, org.json

In a CSV file I have data like below, using CSV reader I reading data as String then I am using `org.json.JsonArry` to get data from String form to List form

```
[*5, 1:, H:, AS005, NB010, PW045, NP090, NP810, IO905, DF915, HG905, TY910, JK925, M:]
```

in the above data after `1` and `H` I have `:` which is causing issue, I have to read this data as it is and there some other data which have special characters like `{B` etc

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: You have chosen a wrong tool to parse that string. It is not valid JSON.

Comment: `[AS007, DF007, ER897]` this is also one kind of data which is available in CSV file, for this kind of data I am not getting any error when I use JsonArray

Answer (score 0):

For those which are not having data with special characters are treated as JsonArray but which have special characters are showed as invalid data. So I used basic java concept i.e

```
String data = "[*5, 1:, H:, AS005, NB010, PW045, NP090, NP810, IO905, DF915, HG905, TY910, JK925, M:]"
data.replaceAll("\\[", "");
data.replaceAll("\\]", "");
List<String> actualMainList = new ArrayList<>();
String[] mainArray = main.split(",");
for(String s : mainArray){
   actualMainList.add(s.trim());
}
```